# Projection of $V$ onto $U$ along $T$ ?

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help with my proofs. :)

Let $ V = U_1 \oplus W = U_2 \oplus W $ and $\pi_1 : V \to V$ the projection of $V$ onto $U_1$ along $W$ and $\pi_2: V \to V$ the projection of V onto $U_2$ along $W$.

1) If $U_1 = U_2$ then follows: $\pi_1 \circ \pi_2 = \pi_2 \circ \pi_1$. Since for any element $u \in U_1$ it is $u \in U_2$.
So I should be able to show $\pi_1 \circ \pi_2 = \ldots = \pi_2 \circ \pi_1$ since the two projections should be the same, but:

But: What exactly IS $\pi_1 \circ \pi_2$ ?

I'm sure I need this information to proof that

2) if $\pi_1 \circ \pi_2 = \pi_2 \circ \pi_1$ then $U_1 = U_2$.

Comment: Try using Grassman's formula to show $\dim U_1 = \dim U_2$, and then, using the conditions given, show that the restriction $\pi_2: U_1 \to U_2$ is injective. Also, I'm not sure if the projective-space tag quite applies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just function composition. For any $v$ then $\pi_{1}\circ\pi_{2}(v)=\pi_{1}(\pi_{2}(v))$, and $\pi_{2}\circ\pi_{1}(v)=\pi_{2}(\pi_{1}(v))$. Warning, some book use the left-to-right function composition convention, in which the above is reversed: not that it matters in your case of course, but it's wise to check the book for sure.

Comment: Ok, so.. 1) For any $ v = u+w \in V$ I'll get $ \pi_1(\pi_2(v)) = \pi_1(u) = u$ and $ \pi_2(\pi_1(v)) = \pi_2(u) = u.$. Am I right? Since my condition was $ U_1 = U_2 $. 2) If $u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in U_2$ I should get $\pi_1(\pi_2(u_2+w)) = \pi_1(u_2) = \pi_2(u_1)= \pi_2(\pi_1(u_1+w))$ What is $\pi_1(u_2)$ ?

Comment: @K.L.: yes you're correct. For (2) you actually only have to care about vector in $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$: think of it like a ping pong game where the ball is passed through using $W$. So let's say $u_{2}\in U_{2}$ is written as $u_{1}+w$ where $u_{1}\in U_{1},w\in W$. Then $u_{1}=u_{2}+(-w)$. So $\pi_{1}(u_{2})=u_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}(u_{1})=u_{2}$.